# Router Error with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the current controller's name from the following line:

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

I found that line here:

```
https://gist.github.com/svizion/2325988
```

This is how I'm trying to use it in a hook.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Sys_prescript {
    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $public_access = array('login', 'registration');    
        if (!in_array($this->router->fetch_class(), $public_access)) 
        {
            $user_id = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');
            if (($user_id == FALSE) || (is_numeric($user_id) == FALSE) && (strlen($user_id) < 5))
            {
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only issue is I"m getting the following errors.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Sys_prescript::$router
Filename: controllers/sys_prescript.php
Line Number: 9

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_class() on a non-object in...
```

Comment: Use hook instead of checking the router.. pre_system hook to achieve this

Comment: If the hook is system level then you can get the URL details from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable this is simple why you want to try in router class

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the code, but try:

```
class Sys_prescript {
private $CI;

public function is_logged_in(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $public_access = array('login', 'registration');    
        if (!in_array($this->CI->router->fetch_class(), $public_access)) 
        {
            $user_id = $this->CI -> session -> userdata('user_id');
            if (($user_id == FALSE) || (is_numeric($user_id) == FALSE) && (strlen($user_id) < 5))
            {
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For accessing the singleton instance of CI, call your hook in `post_controller_constructor` instead of calling it in `pre_controller`. `post_controller_constructor` is called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening

Comment: is this tested i don't think so this will work for the pre_system the session library is not available or try load it manually and see what is coming

Comment: As great as a suggestion this is, I unfortunately get the same result.

Comment: I call it "pre controller".

Comment: Have made an edit `$this->CI -> session -> userdata('user_id')` instead of `$this->session->userdata('user_id')`

Comment: I love your help, I just don't understand why this isn't working for me.

Comment: I am now getting: 
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/sys_prescript.php
Line Number: 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_class() on a non-object in sys_prescript.php on line 10

Comment: yes, i am checking on it, will let you know the response

Comment: I suggest you to change the hook point to `post_controller_constructor`.